# AttributeError: object has no attribute Python Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error, hashcode, attributeerror

I have this code but it doesn't work fine.

**POINT**

```
class Point:
    I = 0
    J = 1

    def __init__(self, i: int, j: int):
        self._coordinate = [i, j]  # list

    # ..other code (getter and setter)

    def __key(self):
        return self.get_i(), self.get_j()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Point):
            return self.__key() == other.__key()
        return NotImplemented

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__key())
```

**PointType**

```
class PointType(Point):

    def __init__(self, i: int, j: int, t: int):
        Point.__init__(self, i, j)
        self.__t = t

    # getters and setters
```

**BOMB:**

```
class Bomb(Thread, PointType):

    def __init__(self, i: int, j: int):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        PointType.__init__(self, i, j, BOMB)

    def run(self) -> None:
        # code
```

When i start Bomb Thread, this program gives me this error: ***AttributeError: 'Bomb' object has no attribute '_coordinate'***
I presume the error is ****hash****.

**Full stack trace:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "D:\Mario\Documents\BomberFriends\application\model\games.py", line
> 634, in 
> plant()   File "D:\Mario\Documents\BomberFriends\application\model\games.py", line
> 589, in plant
> gameInstance.plantBomb(i, j)   File "D:\Mario\Documents\BomberFriends\application\model\games.py", line
> 151, in plantBomb
> Bomb(i, j).start()   File "D:\Mario\Documents\BomberFriends\application\model\games.py", line
> 238, in **init**
> Thread.**init**(self)   File "C:\Users\Mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py",
> line 822, in **init**
> _dangling.add(self)   File "C:\Users\Mario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib_weakrefset.py",
> line 85, in add
> self.data.add(ref(item, self._remove))   File "D:\Mario\Documents\BomberFriends\application\model\games.py", line
> 97, in **hash**
> return hash(self.__key())   File "D:\Mario\Documents\BomberFriends\application\model\games.py", line
> 89, in __key
> return self.get_i(), self.get_j()   File "D:\Mario\Documents\BomberFriends\application\model\games.py", line
> 69, in get_i
> return self._coordinate[Point.I] AttributeError: 'Bomb' object has no attribute '_coordinate'

How i can resolve?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and the code which generated it, this will improve the quality of answers

Comment: @MichaelRuth I have update the top answer including the full stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the order of parent initializers in `Bomb`. Reversing the order eliminates the error:

```py
class Bomb(Thread, PointType):
    def __init__(self, i: int, j: int):
        PointType.__init__(self, i, j, Bomb)
        Thread.__init__(self)
```